# WPF ListBox.SelectedItems as ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

Is there a way to have the selected items of a `ListBox` as a `ListBoxItem` in the event `SelectionChanged` (on the `ListBox`) in WPF?

Right now, when I call `listBox.SelectedItems` I get the list of items in the format of my data source.

For example, when I create my `ListBox` I bind it to a `CustomListBoxViewModel` as a data source, so when I called `SelectedItems` I get a list of `CustomListBoxViewModel` objects.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The code that was given in the chosen answer worked perfectly for my use case.

On the other hand, I completely understand that this is a violation of the MVVM pattern. I'll use the code you provided in code behind of a xaml view.

The reason behind my original question was that I need to implement a `ListBox` that has some disabled `ListBoxItems` inside. Those items would have to be unselectable.

I tried to use an Attached Property *IsSelectable* on my `ListBoxItems` and it didn't work well. This attached property was greatly inspired by this [post](https://coderelief.net/2011/01/04/non-selectable-listboxitem-or-listviewitem-using-attached-properties/). The problem was that when I was directly selecting a disabled item, the attached property worked perfectly. The item couldn't be selected and it wasn't inside the *SelectedItems* collection. But if I wanted to select all the items by pressing CTRL+A, all the `ListBoxItems` were selected even the disabled ones and were found in the *SelectedItems* collection.

Comment: No, that's not how it works.

Comment: @Will I updated the question with the reason I want to do that. This is the "best" way of doing it I thought of... Maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever reason you're doing this for, it's probably a serious violation of MVVM that you'll bitterly regret for the rest of your life.

But the first step on the road to perdition is always an easy one.

Here's how:

```
var listBox = (ListBox)sender;
var selectedListBoxItems = 
    listBox.SelectedItems.Cast<Object>()
    .Select(item => (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item))
    .ToList();
```

Just don't come crying to me when it all ends in tears.

No but seriously, there's *are* a few good reasons to do this kind of thing in WPF, but they're far less common than somebody new to WPF would expect. Pretty much any normal case is best handled by having your C# code interacting only with your data items, and do stuff to the ListBoxItems in XAML via styles and templating. Once you get used to that way of thinking, it's very powerful, flexible, productive, and maintainable. Codebehind is what you do for odd cases when all other reasonable avenues fail. Drag and drop, for example.

Comment: I totally understand that this is bad. I added the reason why I was asking this in the edit of my question. Maybe there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @m.lachance Reading your updated question, my first reaction is "Oh, man, just kludge it in codebehind". This is definitely the kind of thing you'd often do in codebehind -- an attached property solution may be better, but very often the real world schedule just doesn't allow you to build the Parthenon. But stealing the Parthenon is another matter; I'll take a look at that coderelief.net post and see if that code works for me.

Comment: I wish this was all much easier. For example auto scrolling of a listbox. what a hell. I always end up by naming the control and directly call ScrollIntoView. :-(